# .click / .insertAfter creates 2 divs instead of 1

Tags: jquery, click, insertafter

first time posting here, hope I'm doing everything right :)

I'm kind of new to the whole programming thing and I've started to try different things out. Right now I'm playing with jQuery and having a little problem here.

This is my jQuery-Code:

```js
$('#objekt1 ul li a').click(function() {
    $('<div id="objekt2"></div>').insertAfter("#objekt1");
});
```

When I click on a link inside a list inside a div, I want to insert a new div after the first one (`#objekt1`). The thing is, when I click the link, I get two new divs instead of just one

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

This is what the html code looks like:

```html
<body>

    <div id="objekt1">
        <ul id="listeNamen">
            <li><a href=""> Hans Mustername </a></li>
            <li> Hans Mustername </li>
            <li> Hans Mustername </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    

</body>
```

Comment: What output the console of your browser ?

Comment: Works normal for me, see this link: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgu8u8b6/1/)

Comment: Could it be a problem with codecademy? (I'm writing my code on the codecademy website )

Comment: share your HTML markup. Maybe you are binding event twice, maybe an event propagation issue, maybe etc...

Comment: Added my HTML code, sorry

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in your code. Take a look this code http://jsfiddle.net/xv14j3hL/

```
<div id="objekt1">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">anchor</a></li>
    </ul>
</div> 
<script>   
    $('#objekt1 ul li a').click(function() { 
        $('<div id="objekt2">newdiv</div>').insertAfter( "#objekt1" ); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Could be a problem with codecadamy then (I'm writing my code on their website)?